# Import not found: getCleanUrl

Tags: javascript, msw

I try to use MSW with '@web/dev-server' and always get a
`Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: getCleanUrl`

coming form `http://localhost:8000/node_modules/msw/lib/esm/RequestHandler-deps.js`

The most minimal example I can come up is:

```
<script type="module">
        import { setupWorker, rest } from 'msw';
        window.onload = function () {
            const worker = setupWorker(

                rest.get('/test', (req, res, ctx) => {

                    return res(
                        ctx.json({
                           value: 'test',
                        })
                    )
                }),
            )

            worker.start();
        }
    </script>
```

inside the index.html

The thing is, I can see getCleanUrl inside the browser debugger when I navigate inside the node_modules folder to it.

Also the mockServiceWorker.js is set correctly on the root, I can navigate to it via `http://localhost:8000/mockServiceWorker.js`

So I am very confused why the browser complains about not finding it..

Comment: Resolving files from the node_modules folder is done for you by webpack. For the browser, you need to be explicit on the path.

Comment: yes, I've learned that  mswjs isn't supported natively in the browser...